# How can I print a line break in a stacktrace?

Tags: crashlytics

`\n` doesn't seem to work.

I should mention this extraordinary case, in which the `\n` does the trick.

```
Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()).replaceAll(",", "\n")
```

In fact, if I try to do

```
catch {
    Crashlytics.logException(new IllegalStateException(
            Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()).replaceAll(",", "\n") + ".\n" +
            "b"
    ));
}
```

The stacktrace is printed with every entry on one line, *BUT* `b` is printed on the same line the stacktrace finishes.

This is just an example with the stacktrace, all the others

```
  Crashlytics.logException(new IllegalStateException(
        "a\nb"
  ));
```

do not work and do print `ab` indeed.

Note that this counts even for the "expanded" stacktrace, in other words, when you click on the `</>raw` button  and the stacktrace expands, the two letters are still on the same line.

How can I print a line break in Crashlytics?

Comment: How does \r\n work? Or did you figure this out some other way?